# Shopify Python API Variant Options Don't Write To Store

Tags: python, api, shopify

I can't seem to create a product with multiple options. I've tried everything and the documentation from Shopify's official library is poor. I've looked all over the API reference guide and search other forms, but can't seem to find the proper syntax. Code is below. I'm trying to create a product with two options, for instance option1 is size and option2 is color. There are no error messages shown too for the printed output, but variant options doesn't appear in the Shopify store, only the product with 0 variants appears.

```
new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "My Product"
new_product.handle = "test-product"
##what I've tried... and countless others
#First example of new_product.variants
new_product.variants = shopify.Variant({'options': {'option1' : ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'], 'option2' : ['Black', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red']}, 'product_id': '123456789'})
#Second example of new_product.variants
new_product.variants = shopify.Variant({'options': [{'option1': 'Size', 'option2': 'Colour','option3': 'Material'}]})
#Thrid example of new_product.variants
new_product.variants = shopify.Variant([
                      {'title':'v1', 'option1': 'Red', 'option2': 'M'},
                      {'title':'v2', 'option1' :'Blue', 'option2' :'L'}
                      ])
new_product.save()
##No errors are output, but doesn't create variants with options
if new_product.errors:
    print new_product.errors.full_messages()
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation is actually correct, however it is admittedly confusing. The three main points it seems you're missing:

- The option names are set on the product, not the variants
- `Product.variants` is a list of `Variant` resources; you need a `Variant` resource for every variant you want
- You simply set a string to each of `Variant`'s `option1`, `option2`, and `option3` attributes

**Example:**

```
import shopify

# Authenticate, etc
# ...

new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "My Product"
new_product.handle = "test-product"
new_product.options = [
    {"name" : "Size"},
    {"name" : "Colour"},
    {"name" : "Material"}
]

colors = ['Black', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Red']
sizes = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']

new_product.variants = []
for color in colors:
    for size in sizes:
        variant = shopify.Variant()
        variant.option1 = size
        variant.option2 = color
        variant.option3 = "100% Cotton"
        new_product.variants.append(variant)

new_product.save()
```

It's important to note that each variant's option combinations must be unique, or it will return an error. A quirk that isn't documented is that when you don't supply any `options` on the parent `Product` resource, it will implicitly give you a single option named `Style`, and likewise if you don't assign any options on the variant then it will automatically assign `Default Title` to each variant's `option1`. Since each option combination is unique, if you don't assign any `options` or `option1` values, then it won't error when you only have a single variant. If you then try with multiple variants, the error it will give you will be confusing, as it will be referring to the non-uniqueness of variant options and not about missing the `options` and `option1` parameters.

Comment: Thank you, this one save me lots of trial and error!